# Node.JS - Wait for a function to finish before executing rest of code

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am not a professional with Node.JS and Javascript as a whole, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question.

I am running a Node.JS server to accept socket connections for a website that I will be running, and part of what this script is meant to do is contact a database. I have a function that is designed to do this before starting the server. However, when I call the function it continues with the rest of the code anyway and does not wait for the function to finish. I have tried using callbacks but to no avail, and I have no clue how to use Promises. Can someone explain how I resolve this issue?

Here is my code for reference:

```
function GetCompetitionInfo(competitionID,callback){
    var competitionInfo = {
        id:competitionID,
        title:"",
        topic:"",
        difficulty:"",
        description:"",
        jackpot:0,
        answer:0,
        author:0
    }
    var testVariable;
    sqlConnection_read.connect(function(err){
       if(err) throw err;
       console.log("Connected to TSDB, retrieving competition info...");
       var query = "SELECT * FROM competitions WHERE PuzzleID="+competitionID+";";
       sqlConnection_read.query(query,function(err,result){
          if(err) {console.log("Uh oh spaghettiohs");throw err;}
          competitionInfo.title = result[0].Puzzle_Title;
          competitionInfo.topic = result[0].Puzzle_Topic;
          competitionInfo.difficulty = result[0].Puzzle_Difficulty;
          competitionInfo.description=result[0].puzzle_description;
          competitionInfo.answer=result[0].Puzzle_Answer;
          competitionInfo.jackpot=result[0].Puzzle_Jackpot;
          competitionInfo.author=result[0].Puzzle_Author;  
          callback(competitionInfo);
       });
    });
}
GetCompetitionInfo(0,function(data){
   competitionInfo=data;//This is a variable outside of the scope
});
//I want this to be executed afterwards
var competitionTitle = competitionInfo.title;
var competitionTopic = competitionInfo.topic;
var competitionDifficulty = competitionInfo.difficulty;
var competitionDescription = competitionInfo.description;
var competitionAnswer = competitionInfo.answer;
var jackPotTotal = competitionInfo.jackpot;
var competitionAuthor = competitionInfo.author;

console.log("Title:"+competitionTitle);
console.log("Topic:"+competitionTopic);
console.log("Difficulty:"+competitionDifficulty);
console.log("Description:"+competitionDescription);
console.log("Answer:"+competitionAnswer);
console.log("Jackpot:"+jackPotTotal);
console.log("Author UID:"+competitionAuthor);
```

But this seems to immediately execute before the GetCompetitionDetails function has finished. How do I make them execute one after the other?

Comment: Simply put it in the callback or return a promise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NodeJS` and `JavaScript` makes use of `callbacks` to control the flow of your application. `Promises` simplify the code so you don't end up in something called `callback hell`.

Easiest fix it to move your assignments into the callback:

```
// function(data) { ... } is the callback that will be executed AFTER GetCompetitionInfo is finished. Anything you want to do after will have to be in that function.
GetCompetitionInfo(0, function(data){

   // everything in this block will be run AFTER GetCompetitionInfo is finished
   competitionInfo=data;

    var competitionTitle = competitionInfo.title;
    var competitionTopic = competitionInfo.topic;
    var competitionDifficulty = competitionInfo.difficulty;
    var competitionDescription = competitionInfo.description;
    var competitionAnswer = competitionInfo.answer;
    var jackPotTotal = competitionInfo.jackpot;
    var competitionAuthor = competitionInfo.author;

    console.log("Title:"+competitionTitle);
    console.log("Topic:"+competitionTopic);
    console.log("Difficulty:"+competitionDifficulty);
    console.log("Description:"+competitionDescription);
    console.log("Answer:"+competitionAnswer);
    console.log("Jackpot:"+jackPotTotal);
    console.log("Author UID:"+competitionAuthor);

});
```

For more info about all of this check the answer in the duplicate question: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Man, I feel rather silly right now. x.x It really was that simple. I was going to try that solution but thought that would have not worked so I didn't. Oh well. Thank you anyway. <3

Comment: No worries, it's a mistake you only make once. I would recommend bookmarking the duplicate question that was posted, it's very well written and it explains how synchronous/asynchronous behavior works in JavaScript. Don't worry if you don't understand all of it yet, just keep it around for reference when you need it.